# I am facing the problem on Jmeter wherein the scenario is not getting started on clicking the start button

Tags: jmeter

I am facing the problem on Jmeter wherein I am trying to run the simple scenario that includes thread group, http request, http header manager and view results tree. When I am clicking on the Start button then nothing is happening. How can I resolve this problem? Please help.

**

```
INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: view event page 2-1
INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)**
```

This is the error that I am getting as displayed in log viewer on Jmeter.

Comment: Can you post code or more context to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check :

- that thread group properties are ok particularly if you checked thread lifetime
- if you are using CSV DataSet, check that the csv is found

Can you show full jmeter.log and run Tools > Schematic Overview of your plan

Comment: I just closed the Jmeter and opened it again so now it is running the scripts.